# Why does adding a repository in GitHub Desktop locally not show my pull requests

Tags: github, pull-request, github-desktop, github-enterprise

So I have a GitHub Enterprise account. On GitHub Desktop when I clone my repository from the server it goes under Enterprise and I can see the list of branches and Pull requests as shown below.
[image]

If I simply add an existing repository from my local machine onto GitHub Desktop, then it goes under Other and now I can't see the option for showing me my pull requests.
[image]

I don't want to have to reclone all my repo because that just seems silly but is there a way I can still see if there's any pull request from my repo that I simply added in from my local machine?